# Angular 4 wont load the font that i want

Tags: html, css, angular

I am new to angular four and want to make my page renders with a specific font. But angular just wont load the font at all keeping in mind that it loads others fine but this one in particular is not getting loaded although the same html and css works perfect when using them with any other framework can you guys help me here is the code:
my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-font',
  templateUrl: './test-font.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-font.component.css']
})
export class TestFontComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

the html:

```
 <p>
  test-font works!
</p>
```

the css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: GothamRegular;
    src: url("Gotham Light Regular.otf");
}

p {
    font-family: GothamRegular;
    font-size:50px;       
}
```

the name of the font :Gotham Regular

Comment: Are you sure you've got the path (check the Network helper to figure out where Angular is trying to load the file from) and name of the file correct (including the spaces and the extension)?

Comment: solved by just removing all the spacing int the font name ans thanks for the hint @potatopeelings it was a confusing error that wasted me 2 hours , if you like you can post it as an answer so i can accepted so you get the credit

Comment: That's alright - that advice was very generic :-). Feel free to add an answer with the additional details if you wish though. Cheers!